# Does a two field table (both int) need an index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table which has only two fields, id1 and i2.

Both are ids from other tables and are int(10).

Should I have an index on this table?

Edit: What I'm thinking is that this table is made up of two simple data types... would MySQL query the non-indexed data less efficiently than the indexed data?

The table in question will have more reads than writes and wouldn't be queried very often so an index would be fine to have.

Comment: Indexing is as much an art as it is a science.  Generally speaking if a table has fewer writes than reads indexes are generally a good thing.  If a table has fewer than 20k rows indexes will get you a little but not alot.  If this table is to be used in LOTS of joins within your system and always references both columns; a combined index may serve you best; really it just depends on what performance is acceptable.  If you can live with 0.25 sec response times than an index on this size isn't likely needed.  There's two sides to the coin; longer writes vs shorter reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a large table (i.e., consisting of many rows) an index on the columns that will be used as part of a query may be a good idea. Also, if the table will be updated very infrequently and used very often as a relator table, one or more indexes may considerably speed up joins involving the table.

The fact that the two columns in the table refer to primary keys does not obviate the need for an index. Consider a common join scenario involving a relator table such as:

Table1 JOIN RelatorTable JOIN Table2

It may be a good idea to create an index for RelatorTable on the foreign key in that table which refers to the primary key of Table1. This may speed up joins, especially if RelatorTable is large.

Comment: Thanks. After also speaking to some colleagues I now know searching an index is always faster. But when adding an index you must take into account read/write frequency.

Answer (score -2):

Index in SQL databases are much like the ones you have in books, instead of going through the contents of the book to find whatever you are looking for, you use the index rather and then jump to the exact page. But in your case, your table does not contain data, just references to data stored in other table(s) so I personally don't really see the need for an index here. The id field fields can simply function as indexes in this case.